# Access to the component type of tuple struct

Tags: rust

I want to use a tuple struct as the key of a HashMap. The tuple struct has exactly one component, which is an u32. The struct itself does not implement Hash, so itself can't be directly used as key. However, I can always use the underlying u32 as key.

```
struct St(u32);  // defined in a crate not owned by me

let s = St(1);
let mut m = HashMap::<u32, i32>::new();
m.insert(s.0, 2);
```

Question: is there a way to instead of hard-coding the u32 in the HashMap declaration, we use the actual component type of `St`, so that if `St` changes it to something like isize, it still works. Something like C++'s decltype:

```
struct St(isize);  // the crate changes this
let mut m = HashMap::<decltype(St.0), i32>::new();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust has no equivalent of C++'s `decltype`, but you can always make a type alias which is used in both places

```
type StImpl = u32;
struct St(StImpl);

let mut m = HashMap::<StImpl, i32>::new();
```

And, of course, you could also have `St` just directly derive `Hash` and `Eq` to use it in the hash map in the first place.

```
#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct St(isize);

let mut m = HashMap::<St, i32>::new();
```

Now the derived `impl`s will automatically update if you change the internals of `St`.

---

In response to the question edit, I'll propose what I would do here. If you really want to future-proof your code against changes to the library you don't control, you can wrap `St` in a custom `struct` whose `Hash` and `Eq` delegate to the internals. Something like

```rust
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

// Derive Clone, Copy, and anything else useful St implements here.
struct StWrapper(St);

impl Hash for StWrapper {

  fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H) {
    self.0.0.hash(hasher);
  }

}

impl PartialEq for StWrapper {
  fn eq(&self, rhs: &Self) -> bool {
    self.0.0 == rhs.0.0
  }
}

impl Eq for StWrapper {}
```

Our implementations all reference the inside of `St` (via `self.0.0`) but we never actually mention the type of it, so as long as the inner type is something that at least gives us `Eq` and `Hash`, this will continue to work even if the specific type changes. So we can use `StWrapper` as our key type in a `HashMap` and be assured that it's protected against future changes to the library.

It is up to you to weigh whether your particular use case warrants this much boilerplate to future-proof against changes to another library, or whether it's worth it to just use `u32` and tank the cost if they do change implementations. Note that, while this approach does require a decent bit of code, it is very likely to be a zero-cost abstraction at runtime, since `St`, `StWrapper`, and the inner type should all compile down to the same representation in most cases (not guaranteed, but likely), and all of the `hash` and `eq` calls are resolved statically.

Comment: Sorry. Should've clarified that the tuple struct is defined and owned by a crate, not by me. Updated the question.

Comment: Fair enough. See the edit in my post if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I (or someone) could write a macro to simplify the boilerplate.